# Android blackbox test, cannot find test target class

Tags: android, android-studio, robotium, android-instrumentation

I'm having trouble with testing an android project.

I have a debug apk with no source. The start activity class is

```
com.restfriedchicken.android.MainActivity
```

And I get it installed using

```
adb install -r app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
```

Then I create a new project with the following build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.restfriedchicken.android.test">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application android:allowBackup="false">
        <!-- linkage for the test runner -->
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.restfriedchicken.android" />

</manifest>
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.3.1'
    compile 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.51'
}
```

But when I run tests, it reports cannot find "com.restfriedchicken.android.MainActivity":

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Didn't find class "com.restfriedchicken.android.MainActivity" on path: 
DexPathList[
    [
        zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", 
        zip file "/data/app/com.restfriedchicken.android.test.test-1.apk", 
        zip file "/data/app/com.restfriedchicken.android.test-1.apk"
    ],
    nativeLibraryDirectories=[
        /data/app-lib/com.restfriedchicken.android.test.test-1, 
        /data/app-lib/com.restfriedchicken.android.test-1, 
        /system/lib
    ]
]
```

It seems like the instrumentation does not succeed?

Answer (score 0):

I just got it to work. I move the tests from src/androidTest to src/main and run the test by the following steps:

```
./gradlew clean :app:assembleDebug
adb install -r app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
adb shell am instrument -w com.restfriedchicken.android.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

But if I run android test using android studio, it does not work.